# How to increase space between the given two stacked bars?

Tags: r, ggplot2

How to increase space between the given two stacked bars (e.g., between second and third stacked bars) for the following code? The rest space does not need to be changed. Thanks a lot!

```
library(ggplot2)
rm(list = ls())

Year      <- c(rep(c("2006-07", "2007-08", "2008-09", "2009-10"), each = 4))
Category  <- c(rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), times = 4))
Frequency <- c(168, 259, 226, 340, 216, 431, 319, 368, 423, 645, 234, 685, 166, 467, 274, 251)
Data      <- data.frame(Year, Category, Frequency)

ggplot(Data, aes(x = Year, y = Frequency, fill = Category, label = Frequency)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",width = 0.8) +
  geom_text(size = 3, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick hack, but colleagues with more expertise will no doubt provide more elegant answers:

1. rename `Year` to something else, and add a new continuous `Year` that represents the gaps you want:

```
Data <- Data %>% rename(grp=Year) %>% mutate(Year = rep(c(1,2,4,5),each=4))
```

2. add `scale_x_continuous()` indicating the breaks and labels you want.

```
scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(1,2,4,5),labels = unique(Data$grp))
```

[image: bar_with_space]

Answer (score 2):

You could change the `xmin` of your third bar and `xmax` of your second bar using `ggplot_build`. I changed it with 0.1 so you can modify that. Here is a reproducible example:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
Year      <- c(rep(c("2006-07", "2007-08", "2008-09", "2009-10"), each = 4))
Category  <- c(rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), times = 4))
Frequency <- c(168, 259, 226, 340, 216, 431, 319, 368, 423, 645, 234, 685, 166, 467, 274, 251)
Data      <- data.frame(Year, Category, Frequency)

p <- ggplot(Data, aes(x = Year, y = Frequency, fill = Category, label = Frequency)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(size = 3, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) 

# Old plot
p
```

[image]

```r
q <- ggplot_build(p)

# Here you can decide the distance between specific bars
q$data[[1]] <- q$data[[1]] %>%
  mutate(xmin = ifelse(x == 3, xmin + 0.1, xmin),
         xmax = ifelse(x == 2, xmax - 0.1, xmax))

q <- ggplot_gtable(q)
# New plot
plot(q)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: hah.. +1, as I said more expertise = more elegance! :)

Comment: Haha thanks @langtang! ggplot_build is always useful!